# compare the values of two text boxes and validate them in a session in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I  code to generate captcha at page load. Here is the code.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


        Bitmap objBMP = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(60, 20);
        Graphics objGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(objBMP);
        objGraphics.Clear(Color.Green);
        objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        Font objFont = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Italic);
        string randomStr = "";
        int[] myIntArray = new int[5];
        int x;
        Random autoRand = new Random();
        for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {

            myIntArray[x] = System.Convert.ToInt32(autoRand.Next(0, 9));
            randomStr += (myIntArray[x].ToString());

        }
        Session.Add("randomStr", randomStr);
        objGraphics.RotateTransform(-7F);
        objGraphics.DrawString(randomStr, objFont, Brushes.White, 3, 3);
        Response.ContentType = "image/Gif";
        objBMP.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
        objFont.Dispose();
        objGraphics.Dispose();
        objBMP.Dispose();

}
```

Now I want to validate between inputed value and generated captcha. Just like as

```
if (Page.IsValid && (txtInput.Text.ToString() == Session["randomStr"].ToString()))
```

Here I have saved query.of user using four text boxes.

```
 public static string SaveEnquiry(string name, string email, string contact, string comments, string Company, string items, string ip,string captcha)
{
    string StrReturn = "";
    try
    {
        UserContactUs objUserContactUs = new UserContactUs();
        string userCmt = "User Comment:" + comments; ;
        int result = objUserContactUs.insertContactUs(name, contact, email, userCmt, GetUser_IP());
        if (result > 0)
        {
            string mesageRec = name + " has enquired for " + ". Contact : " + contact + ", Email: " + email+ ". His Cmt: " + comments ;
            //SendSMSToAdmin(mesageRec);
            //SendSMSToUser(contact.TrimStart('0'));
            StrReturn = "1#Thanks, for your interest.We will get back to you soon";


        }
        else
        {
            StrReturn = "0#Your enquiry is not saved. Please try Again!";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StrReturn = "0#" + ex.Message;
    }
    return StrReturn;
}
```

Now I want is if both the fields(i.e captcha image  and inputtext box) are not equal then refresh the captcha image by showing a message invalid captcha.

Here is my contact form.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
                    <img height="50" id="EnquiryCaptcha" alt="" style="border:inset;" src="InsertEnquiry.aspx" width="130">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-15">
                    <input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput" placeholder="Captcha*" style="margin-top:auto; border:groove;">
                </div>
                <!--end-->
                <button class="border-button " data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="1000" type="button" id="btnsubmit" onclick="InsertEnquiry('contactForm')" name="submit">Send Message</button>
```

Comment: You may as well [edit] post and add actual problem you are facing with posted code. It the same time please read [MCVE] guidance and see if any part of the code can be removed. Also avoid using `>` unless you providing citations from somewhere (you'd need to link to source and give attribution in that case anyway)

Comment: Post ur Error code also

Comment: i can't get the value of Enquiry captcha text field because it is in html code(it says EnquiryCaptcha does't exist in current context) and i want to access it in .cs code.